# How to manually fire click event with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following structure in my html page, where I have populated a number of dropdowns with php. The following is the final structure

```
<ul id='nav'>
             <li><a href='#' id='s7' >Heading 1</a>
<ul>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>one</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>two</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>three</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>four</li></a>

              </ul>
</li></ul>


<ul id='nav'>
             <li><a href='#' id='s8' >Heading 2</a>
<ul>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>five</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>six</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>seven</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>eight</li></a>


              </ul></li></ul>
```

I have an onclick set up on these to properly `close` and `open` the `ul` on clicking as below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){

    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {

      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {

      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});
```

I require to open different headings based on value given by user. If user gives s7 I shall open `Heading 1` to drop down and if user gives s8 I shall drop `Heading 2` down.

I'm trying to fire onclick event with the following code

```
$("#nav > li > a#s7").trigger("click");
```

If user input is s7 but it is not triggering the onclick as setup above.

Kindly update how I can trigger the onclick and slide the menu for `Heading 1` down and accordingly as per value `Heading 2` down.
Thanks.

Comment: `$("#nav > li > a#s7").get(0).click();`

Comment: seems fine - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tut63/1/

Comment: since you have an id `$("#s7").click();` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Please try with the below code snippet. I am not able to reproduce issue with your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
<title>Test</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id='nav'>
             <li><a href='#' id='s7' >Heading 1</a>
<ul>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>one</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>two</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>three</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>four</li></a>

              </ul>
</li></ul>


<ul id='nav'>
             <li><a href='#' id='s8' >Heading 2</a>
<ul>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>five</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>six</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>seven</li></a>
<a href='coursedetail.php'><li class='lidiv'>eight</li></a>


              </ul></li></ul>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav > li > a").on("click", function(e){

    if($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    if(!$(this).hasClass("open")) {

      // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
      $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
      $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

      // open our new menu and add the open class
      $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
      $(this).addClass("open");
    }

    else if($(this).hasClass("open")) {

      $(this).removeClass("open");
      $(this).next("ul").slideUp(350);
    }
  });
});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note : Now excute below code in browser console window and check it.

> $("#nav > li > a#s7").trigger("click");

Comment: with $(#id).click() it is working.i dont know why earlier it was not working with $("#nav > li > a#s7").trigger("click");

Comment: if i am writting only this <script language="javascript">
 
    $("#s<?php echo $stream; ?>").trigger("click");

</script> where $stream is 7 it is not working .however on writing this  jQuery(function(){
    $("#s<?php echo $stream; ?>").trigger("click");
}); it is working .can you update

Comment: Sorry but i don't have any idea about PHP. Let me know if you faced same issue in Html page.